trouble sending post request with to laravel end point for razorpay order ceration
when i send a get request here every thing works perfectly fine but post request gives me errors
react method for sending to payment.razorpay route
`const handlePayment = ()=>{
localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', selectedSeats);
axios.post(route('seats.checkAvailability'), { selectedSeats })
.then(response => {
  console.log('Success:', response.data);
  try{
      axios.post(route('payment.razorpay'), {
        selectedSeats,
        totalAmount: total,
        user: auth.user
      },
      {headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}}
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response.data);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('in catch');
  setErr(error.response.data.error);
});

};`
here is the route
Route::post('/razorpay', [PaymentController::class, 'processPayment'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('payment.razorpay');
function in PaymentController
`    public function processPayment( Request $request)
{
    dd('here');

    $request->validate([
        'selectedSeats' => 'required|array',
        'total' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        '$user' => 'required'
    ]);

    $selectedSeats = $request->input('selectedSeats');
    $totalAmount = $request->input('total'); 
    $user = $request->user();

    $api_key = config('services.razorpay.razorpay_key');
    $api_secret = config('services.razorpay.razorpay_secret');
    $api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
    
    try {
    $order = $api->order->create([
        'amount' => $totalAmount * 100,
        'currency' => 'INR',
        'receipt' => 'order_receipt_id_123',
        'payment_capture' => 1 // Auto capture payment
    ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Failed to create Razorpay order'], 500);
    }

    $data = [
        "key"  => $api_key, 
        "amount" => $order['amount'], // In paise
        "currency" => $order['currency'],
        "name" => $user->name,
        "description" => "Ticket Purchase",
        "image" => "https://cdn.razorpay.com/logos/GhRQcyean79PqE_medium.png",
        "prefill" => [
            "name" => $user->name,
            "email" => $user->email
        ],
        "theme" => [
            "color"  => "#3399cc"
        ],
        "order_id" => $order['id'], // Pass the order ID from Razorpay
    ];

    return Inertia::render('Checkout', [
        'data' => $data, // No need to json_encode here, Inertia will handle it
        'selectedSeats' => $selectedSeats, // Pass selected seats to the view
        'totalAmount' => $totalAmount, // Pass the total amount
    ]);
}`

list of routes
GET|HEAD  / ........................................................................................................................................ event.index  
  GET|HEAD  confirm-password .......................................................................... password.confirm › Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@show  
  POST      confirm-password ............................................................................................ Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@store  
  GET|HEAD  dashboard .................................................................................................................................. dashboard  
  POST      email/verification-notification ............................................... verification.send › Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController@store  
  GET|HEAD  events/{event} ........................................................................................................................... events.show  
  GET|HEAD  forgot-password ........................................................................... password.request › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@create  
  POST      forgot-password .............................................................................. password.email › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@store  
  GET|HEAD  login ............................................................................................. login › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@create  
  POST      login ...................................................................................................... Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@store  
  POST      logout .......................................................................................... logout › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@destroy  
  PUT       password ............................................................................................ password.update › Auth\PasswordController@update  
  POST      payment-verify ............................................................................................. payment.verify › PaymentController@verify  
  GET|HEAD  profile ........................................................................................................ profile.edit › ProfileController@edit  
  PATCH     profile .................................................................................................... profile.update › ProfileController@update  
  DELETE    profile .................................................................................................. profile.destroy › ProfileController@destroy  
  POST      razorpay ......................................................................................... payment.razorpay › PaymentController@processPayment  
  GET|HEAD  register ............................................................................................. register › Auth\RegisteredUserController@create  
  POST      register ......................................................................................................... Auth\RegisteredUserController@store  
  POST      reset-password ..................................................................................... password.store › Auth\NewPasswordController@store  
  GET|HEAD  reset-password/{token} ............................................................................ password.reset › Auth\NewPasswordController@create  
  GET|HEAD  sanctum/csrf-cookie ................................................................ sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
  POST      seats/check-availability .................................................................. seats.checkAvailability › SeatController@checkAvailability  
  GET|HEAD  tickets ................................................................................................................................ tickets.index  
  GET|HEAD  up ...................................................................................................................................................  
  GET|HEAD  verify-email ............................................................................ verification.notice › Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController  
  GET|HEAD  verify-email/{id}/{hash} ............................................................................ verification.verify › Auth\VerifyEmailController  

                                                                                                                                               Showing [27] routes  

i tried adding a dd() at the start of the function but the request wont even reach there
i also tried using Inertia.post
should i keep this as a get route cause it works perfectly fine, if yes where should i pass the data ?

There should be some errors in the browser in developer console. Please check and include any relevant errors. Also, include the php artisan route:list result in your question.

@zlatan i do get a 409 conflict for for 'events/3' (event.show) for a split second and then the order is created if i am using get request, for post request ill just red redirected to 'events/3' i have added the route:list in the question

It may be the problem with events route. Just comment out event route and check. Otherwise please include how those routes are configured
